# C++: Do all functions and ivars have to be declared in the .h file?

Tags: c++, objective-c

I'm migrating from C to Obj-C into Obj-C++. I'll be taking my course in into to C++ for next semester. Hopefully, I'll breeze through it.

So in Obj-C, private and public is determined by whatever you declare in your header file. Within a `@interface` of the `.h` file and all properties and instance/class methods that you can call on that class are laid out for you. From what I can assume about C++, I feel like public and private is in fact, all written out in the `.h` file: ivars, functions, what have you. Am I right in this assumption?

Comment: In C++ parlance, we say that the class declaration is in the `.h` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With earlier Objective-C compilers the `@interface` of a class (often declared in the header file, `.h`) had to contain all data members ("ivars").  With the newer LLVM compiler it is possible to list them in the `@implementation` (`.m` file).

Other parts of Objective-C classes are not so restricted.  Methods can be declared or defined in `.h`, `.m`, both, or neither!  Headers typically describe the methods that are most important, omitting things that are implementation-specific.  *Categories* (a feature of the language) are a way to add new methods to a class while declaring and defining them somewhere else.  There are also various ways to use `NSObject` and the Objective-C runtime to do almost anything you can think of, e.g. deciding at runtime whether or not a class has a method, or adding a method, etc.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can have public and private not in various .h files. Not sure about obj-c/c++, but if you do choose to put them in.h files (preferred in bigger programs), you need to #include the .h files.